# ErrorException (E_ERROR) HELP Array to string conversion (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog50\app\views\blog\view.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel-5

//this is the view.blade.php file. it is showing the above error can any one please give ideas whats going wrong . the Route. php file and the blog controller.php is given below. ,maybe the the problem is in controller or route file , i dont know.

///view.blade.php

```
@section ('content')

@include('blog.partials.post', array('post'=> $post))

<hr/>

<section id="comments">

@foreach($post->comments as $comment)

<div class="comment">
    <p>{{$comment->name }} says...</p>
    <blockquote>
        {{$comment->comment}}
    </blockquote>
</div>
@endforeach

</section>
<section>

<h3 class="title">Add a Comment..</h3>
<form action="{{ URL::route('createComment'), array('id'=>$post->id)}}" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group" >
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="your name" class="form-control">

    </div>
    <div class="form-group" >
        <textarea class="form-control" name="content" placeholder="your comment">
        </textarea>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Comment">

</section>


@stop
```

///route.php

```
  Route::get('/', 'BlogController@index');

Route::get('post/new', array(
    'uses'=>'BlogController@newPost',
    'as' =>'newPost',
    ));

Route::post('/post/new' ,array(

    'uses' =>'BlogController@createPost',
    'as' =>'createPost',
    ));

Route::get('post/{id}',array(

    'uses' =>'BlogController@viewPost',
    'as' =>'viewPost',
    ));

Route::post('/post/{id}/comment',array(
     'uses'=>'BlogController@createComment',
     'as' =>'createComment'
    ));
```

////BlogController

```
class BlogController extends BaseController {

    // set this controller's layout
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('blog.index',array(
            'posts'=>Post::all()
            ));
    }

    // TODO: implement all the function we need in this controller

    public function newPost()

    {
         $this->layout->content = View::make('blog.new');


    }

    public function createPost()

    {

       $post= new Post();
       $post->title=Input::get('title');
       $post->content=nl2br(Input::get('content'));
       $post->save(); 

       return Redirect::route('viewPost', array('id'=>$post->id));

    }

    public function viewPost($id)

    {  
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

        $this->layout->content = View::make('blog.view',array(

             'post' =>$post
            ));

    }

    public function createComment($id)

    {  $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

       $Comment= new Comment();
       $Comment->name=Input::get('name');
       $Comment->content=nl2br(Input::get('content'));
       $post->Comments()->save();

       return Redirect::route('viewPost',array('id'=>$post->id));


    }

}
```

Comment: Which line does the error happen?

Comment: @Raptor does not say any particular line number . only says error is in view  file

Comment: I think {{$comment->comment}} or {{$comment->name}} is array . is it ?

Comment: @JYoThI i am not good at finding error... $post maybe

Comment: can you post the sample array of $post   <?php   var_dump($post); ?>

Comment: @JYoThI   if i remove this "{{ URL::route('createComment'), array('id'=>$post->id)}}"   then it shows  but not able to create comments

Comment: i think your parameter should be like this  "{{ URL::route('createComment',array('id'=>$post->id)) }}"

Comment: @JYoThI  that is same as i gave.

Comment: No . you gave parameter outside . i gave inside . take a look on it .

Comment: thanks man @JYoThI  ...yesss.......it is right

Comment: Glad to help you if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @MirthfulNahid

Comment: @JYoThI  i have no reputation that's why i am not able to vote for you ...but thanks immensely.....

Comment: No problem . cool :) @MirthfulNahid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parameter should be like this

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('createComment', array('id'=>$post->id))}}" method="POST">
```

**Note :** laravel blade template `{{}}` is equivalent to `echo` so now your passing parameter outside . so it's trying to echo the array . so here echo can't echo the array variable . that's why it's gave this error.

> Array to string Conversion